# Scala: find cycles in a field (graph)

Tags: scala, find

If I have a class like this:

```
class Component (val name, val description, var subElements : Set[Component])
```

How can I test if a Component contains cycles inside (with a Boolean function) and who started this cycle.
I know well that if I use val instead of var avoid cycles, but I cannot use val.

Comment: How does `val` stop cycles? And you can avoid `var`, you are just choosing not to.

Comment: If the set of subElements is immutable, you can't create a cycle in the graph since you need to have subElements ready before creating the Component, and you can't add the Component to any existing descendant's set of subElements.
I do not want to use val, why do I need a DSL and then I like to initialize subElements after creating the instance of compoent

Comment: Are you looking for a method to find cycles or find repeated components?

Comment: A component repeated is also a cycle.

Comment: @user1826663, depends on how you define cycle. Consider a graph with edges A->B, A->C, B->D, C->D - D is repeated and the graph is not a tree, still it doesn't contain a cycle (if you define cycle as a sequence of directed edges which takes you back to your starting node).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A member of `Component` to return all elements in the graph below which start a cycle. It returns an empty set if there are no cycles.

```
def descendantsWithCycle = {
  def findCycle(current: Component, checked: Set[Component]): Set[Component] =
    if (checked contains current) Set(current)
    else {
      val newChecked = checked + current
      current.subElements.flatMap(findCycle(_, newChecked))
    }

  findCycle(this, Set())
}
```

Comment: If we see the component structure as a tree. This method compares only nodes that are on the same branch, right?

Comment: @Robertiano, if they are not on the same branch, there can't be a cycle AFAIU.

Comment: Hi Péter, I really want to thank you for your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I think you return a cycle-breaking set. I don't think this algorithm returns all elements which are part of a cycle. But I'm not completely sure about it. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a var, don't use it! it's the same with a val or a var:

```
class Component (val name : String, val description : String,  val subElements : Set[Component]){
    def hasCyle(val seen) : Boolean = (seen contains this ||
                                       subElements.exists(item => item.hasCycle(seen + this)))
    def isCyclic = hasCycle(Set())
  }
}
```

you can read hasCycle as it has a cycle if the list you have seen contains the current item, or if any of the subelements are contained in the set you have seen, plus the current item.

Comment: If we see the component structure as a tree. This method compares only nodes that are on the same branch, right?

Comment: the call to isCyclic only looks at elements "below" it. it passes along an empty set (it hasn't seen any elements yet). after it has checked an item, it has seen that item, so it will check its childeren with that element too. In case it's cyclic, it's not a tree, so there is no real 'below' anymore